# Construct Tkinter GUI from different function on multiple python script

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to construct the GUI for observation of results. However, due to the GUI contain multiple modules, each of them contains multiple widgets and I also want to add extra functions in future so I construct multiple python script for each modules. The main module (called test.py) like this:

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import*
import test2
class test:
    def __init__(self,master):
        button = Button(gui, text = 'click here', command = self.printtestcommand)
        button.pack()
gui = Tk()
a = test(gui)
gui.mainloop()
```

The command printtestcommand is on another script (test2.py):

```
def printtestcommand(self):
    print('Test completed')
```

But when I run the test.py script, I encountered this error:

```
AttributeError: 'test' object has no attribute 'printtestcommand'
```

Can anyone point me what I have wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: `self.printtestcommand` will look for `printtestcommand` function inside `test` class in `test.py`, but `printtestcommand` is defined inside `test2.py`.

Comment: Thanks, so is there any way to import the function printtestcommand to class test to be used?

Comment: It depends on where `printtestcommand()` is defined.  Since it has `self` argument, it seems to be defined inside a class.  If it is the case, you need to create an instance of the class in order to use that function, except that it is a static or class method.

Comment: I mean I want printtestcommand to be imported to the class test on test.py so I can use it as a function(self) like other function I created inside test class